# import txt into 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

i got a txt file write like this:

```
T,G,F,F
G,T,T,F
G,T,F,G
T,F,G,T
```

dimen = 4

and i want to import it into array,as dynamic allocating of chars like:
`[T,G,F,F,G,T,T,F,G,T,F,G,T,F,G,T]`

i tried the code beyond but i got an error.

```
void file_2_arr(FILE *file,char *forest_current,int dimen)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    buffer =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (2*dimen-1));
    const char* delim = ",";
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file);
        char* token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", token);
            strcpy(forest_current, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            forest_current++;
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is way too complicated. You're calling 5 functions and you really only need to call one.

You are doing:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file);
```

But, `sizeof` will return the size of the *pointer* and *not* the length of what you allocated. You want:

```
fgets(buffer, 2 * dimen - 1, file);
```

But, `2 * dimen - 1` is too short. It does *not* account for the newline at the end of the line [or the EOS char]. So, you need to change that to `2 * dimen + 2` both for `fgets` *and* `malloc`

Also, don't use `feof`. Just check the return value of `fgets`

You're using `strtok` to strip out a *single* character at a time. This is *very* slow.

Note that `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1 *by definition*. So, eliminate that.

It's *not* clear if you *want* an EOS character on the end of the output buffer or not. But, you're getting one.

Also, you did *not* show the code that calls your function, so how did you ensure that you had enough space in the *caller's* buffer?

You didn't actually specify *what* error you were actually getting, so it's a bit difficult to ensure that the above fixes your issues.

And, there is no need to cast the return of malloc. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

---

If you read a char at a time, you don't need to use `malloc` or a separate buffer. Or, any other functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
file_2_arr(FILE *file, char *forest_current, int dimen)
{

    while (1) {
        int chr = fgetc(file);
        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        switch (chr) {
        case ',':
        case '\n':
            break;
        default:
            *forest_current++ = chr;
            break;
        }
    }

#if 0
    *forest_current = 0;
#endif
}
```